# How to deal with the warnings when importing BNT tools in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm following the steps:

http://code.google.com/p/bnt/wiki/HowToInstall

But only to get a lot of warnings:

```
>> addpath(genpathKPM(pwd))
Warning: Function
D:\MATLAB\R2007b\toolbox\FullBNT-1.0.4\KPMtools\assert.m has the same
name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a
potential name conflict.
> In path at 110
  In addpath at 89
Warning: Function
D:\MATLAB\R2007b\toolbox\FullBNT-1.0.4\KPMtools\isscalar.m has the same
name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a
potential name conflict.
```

Has anyone else met this problem?

Comment: Why don't you grab the updated version 1.0.5 from http://code.google.com/p/bnt/downloads/list

Answer (score 2):

The warning means exactly what it says: BNT contains some functions that have the same name as Matlab built-in functions.

This has the potential to break some functionality, if the new functions are not compatible with the built-in versions, though it all depends on the [path precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60956.html), i.e. where Matlab goes looking for a function that you're calling.

In short, if the new functions are compatible with the built-in versions, you should make sure that you add the path to your toolbox to the top of the Matlab path to ensure that it is always the toolbox versions that are being called (type `path` to check). I hope this is the case, otherwise you should reorganize the toolbox directory structure and put the offending functions in a directory called 'private' (see the path precedence for details).

**EDIT**

The linked documentation claims that the overloaded functions are compatible. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to add the path to top in `addpath(genpathKPM(pwd)) `?

Comment: Did you check? At least in R2010a, addpath adds to the top by default. Otherwise, you add with the '-begin' option in addpath, like so: `addpath(genpathKPM(pwd),'-begin')`